# write to a csv in python 3 is tricky

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had a code in `2.7` that works well for writing `StringIO` object to a csv.

The same code on `python 3.4` won't work even after using `BytesIO`

here is a way to reproduce:

```
import unicodecsv
from io import BytesIO

output= BytesIO()

csv_writer= unicodecsv.writer(output, delimiter=chr(5))
csv_writer.writerow(["column1","column2"])

with open("my.csv", "a") as output_file:
    output_file.write(output)
```

I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: must be str, not _io.BytesIO
```

Any guess? Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't work with Python 2.7 as well on my machine. Any reason you use `unicodecsv` instead of `csv`?

Comment: on python 2.7 it works by adding encoding="utf-8" and using StringIO (And there is no reason to downvote the question)

Comment: Keeping it as a `StringIO` you can just replace `output_file.write(output)` with `output_file.write(output.getvalue())` which will work in both Py versions.

Comment: @AChampion that seems an answer. The question to "Why does @YOBA want a `xxxIO` object" remains unanswered, though.

Comment: @AChampion Great! I will actually keep the BytesIO, I needed that getvalue() thing which I missed, can you post your answer please?